# Write a query for finding section with maximum students SCHOOL(class, section, students)

Tags: sql

I want to find section with maximum students

Comment: You mean something like "select max(students) from school"? for further help pls provide definitions of the table you want to select from and the column you want a maximum from.

Answer (score 0):

It's an example former

select class, section, max(students) from t1
group by class, section
order by 3 desc;